# Setting up KVM with GUI Ubuntu getting download errors

Tags: lubuntu, kvm-virtualization

Hey all I am new to the world of Ubuntu.

I am trying to install [UBUNTU in GUI mode](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-20-04/) so I can log into it like a normal remote desktop would work. So far I installed the GUI by doing this:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

It went through all of its things and i *think* it was sussesfull.

Now I am trying to install the Xrpt so that I can use the remote desktop to get into the GUI Ubuntu.

When trying to use this:

```
sudo apt install xrdp
```

It asks me the normal y/n about hard drive space and when I do Y it seems to do some things but ends up stopping because it was unable to find what it needed via the https links that no longer seem to work?

[image]

I have tried the suggested:

```
apt-get update
```

And that also does not seem to work because of https links not working?

[image]

So am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: Is the machine on a school or corporate network that requires use of a proxy?

Comment: No its just a VM i purchased from racknerds.

Comment: Can the machine ping us.archive.ubuntu.com?

Comment: and you do that by what command?

Comment: The `ping` command. See `man ping`.

Comment: I cant seem to make that work... man ping http://us.archive.ubuntu.com

Comment: `man` is the instruction manual. It's how to use `ping`.